# A number a is said to have a multiplicative inverse with respect to n

Tags: python

A number a is said to have a multiplicative inverse with respect to n if 
there is a positive integer x less than n so that product of a and x mod 
n is 1.

The great mathematician Euler Proved that every positive integer less 
than n that is prime to n(has no common factor with n other than 1)has a 
multiplicative inverse with respect to n.

This problem is to find the number of positive integers less than n have 
a multiplicative inverse with respect to n.

Input Format

The only line of input is a single integer N which is divisible by no 
prime numbers more than 13.

Output Format

One line containing an integer that gives the number of integers less 
than N that have a multiplciative inverse.

Below is the code i have tried

```
  def inverses(a):
      factors=[x for x in range(1,a+1) if a%x==0]
      fac_prime=[2]
      fi_list=[]
      for i in factors:
        for j in (2,i):
          if i%j==0:
              break
          else:
              fac_prime.append(i)
      print(factors)
      for i in range(1,a):
        for j in fac_prime:
          if i%j==0:
              break
          else:
              fi_list.append(i)

       print(fi_list)

       if __name__ == '__main__':
           fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

           n = int(input().strip())

           res = inverses(n)

           fptr.write(str(res) + '\n')

           fptr.close()
```

Sample Input 0

20

Sample Output 0

8

I am not getting correct output, factors list has factor of given number ,fact prime has the prime number of factors, In fi_list I am dividing prime num to the numbers between the given num, if it divides, I am breaking else I am adding to the final list. The list that came out as output is  [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]. As per my program the multiples of 5 should not come but its coming for me.

How can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you complete your code to be a minimal complete example, including expected and actual output?

Comment: You are computing Euler's totient function, which has easy formulas given the prime decomposition of `N` (which is trivial in this case given the stipulation that no prime divisor is greater than 13).

Comment: @FlyingTeller I have edited my code.

Comment: @JohnColeman Can you give me some example.

Comment: Just look at the Wikipedia article on the function. It has an example for N = 36.